# How to convert extracted date in decimal to Datetime in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, etl, data-conversion

I have extracted the date from an EXCEL file which is `42885.4253360301` and date in excel format is `DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS UTC`.
I want to convert the decimal value to `datetime` using oracle function.
How to proceed?

Comment: This `decimal value`, is it a number of days, hours, minutes or seconds or maybe something else ?

Comment: Dont know. I have extracted date from EXCEL file using pervasive tool and got this decimal value.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really know which is the starting point for oracle date calculation with decimal values, but if you take something like:

```
select to_date('01/01/1900', 'dd/mm/yyyy')+42885.4253360301 as my_date from dual;
```

your result is

```
MY_DATE           
-------------------
01/06/2017 10:12:29
```

meaning that you can apply a simple date operation to your excel value by adding it to a starting point. which starting point? I can't really tell, but hopefully this can act as a hint.

Comment: working backwards, I plugged his decimal value into Excel and converted to Date to figure out what Date he actually started with:  May 30, 2017 10:12:29.  Putting that into Oracle and subtracting 42885.4253360301 yields: 30-dec-1899 00:00:00   so you're onto the right idea, however, I suspect you need to use Dec 30, 1899 as your "base" date, (not Jan 1, 1900) and then add to that .. ;)  but yeah, probably easiest way I know of as well.

Comment: Thanks @Ditto for complementing the answer, lets see if this is of any help to Tanmay.

Comment: You are exactly on the right track. Excel does, indeed, start at January 1, 1900. However, Microsoft made a mistake early on, and I believe they decided to never fix it, so that old code doesn't break. Namely, they treated 1900 as a leap year (!!!!!) which now causes all these problems. You can test this very easily in Excel (seeing that the date after 2/28/1900 is, shockingly, 2/29/1900, even though 1900 was not a leap year).

Comment: ditto and @JairHernandez it is working in jair query i have use date 30-DEC-1899 and its working correctly. Thanks :)